# ARCore how to set point cloud in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, point-clouds, arcore, slam

Sorry i am new at ARCore and augmented reality. I have a general question about PointCloud class in Unity.

My question is: Would it be possible to import a point cloud of a room which is scanned by kinect or etc, to Unity to use as PointCloud in an AR application.
As far as i understand if it is possible to register the points relative to device coordinate system and use these points instead of the points generated by the phone, the accuracy of SLAM of ARCore can be increased.

I would be happy if anyone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using Point Cloud Free Viewer from the asset store, but only up to 10-15 million points. I'm not sure how to do it specifically for ARCore, but you can use Vuforia which runs on Android. Here's a PDF detailing this process: https://www.nctechimaging.com/downloads-files/vuforia_application_notes.compressed.pdf

Comment: Thanks i am using Point Cloud Free Viewer with slight modification but what i am asking here is a bit different. I wanted to points in the cloud to increase tracking performance like it is done [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYoAVyF19FI)

Comment: That sounds interesting. How would you place the point cloud correctly in the real world? And then would the device ping off one of these point cloud points and know where every other scanned feature is from the point cloud data?

Comment: Well in my case i use a Transformation matrix to place the point cloud correctly from scanner to Unity coordination system. ARCore uses extracted feature points to locate itself in the real world combined with IMU. So if you know where exactly those points in real space using a scanner and match your extracted feature point with it you get a lot more info than ARCore offers.

Comment: That seems really useful. Have you figured out how to do it since you've asked the question?

Comment: Ah no i did not figure out because ARCore does not allow you to alter their `PointCloud` atm. I figured out the way to transform points from Kinect or any other scanning environment to Unity coordinate system but i am not sure how to use those points after that.

Comment: Do you find a way since this post?